# Count if value exists in two different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need to count the duplicates between two different sheets with a couple additional requirements. Status needs to "Not Active" and Type Needs to be either "Install" or "Upgrade" 
So in the example in the image below the total account numbers that are duplicated and fall under the additional requirements equal 1 for account 123456
I thought about possibly using vlookup but honestly I have no clue how you would mix that with a countif situation.

[image]

Comment: How is 123456 a duplicate? I see the name and status match, but Type is different.  So, for a duplicate to exist, the `Account#, Name, and Status` should be the same, but `Type` doesn't matter?

Comment: @pnuts - ahh, now I see what that part means. Thanks.

Comment: Any reason for not checking for VBA option?

Comment: it can be install or upgrade to match.

Comment: VBA option is not really a good option because I am using this file to create a template to generate from another program I created and I have not tested that program with VBA code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses an additional column in both data sets to identify the records to be compared and an array formula to count the duplicated records.

First add a column in each data set *(use column “E”)* name it *“Key”* and enter this formula for all records:

```
=IF(AND(EXACT(C2,"Not Active"),OR(EXACT(D2,"Install"),EXACT(D2,"Upgrade"))),
CONCATENATE(A2,CHAR(133),B2),"")
```

Can use this version of the same formula:

```
=IF(AND(C2="Not Active",OR(D2="Install",D2="Upgrade")),
A2&CHAR(133)&B2,"")
```

The above formula identifies the records complying with the required criteria:

> Status need to be "Not Active" and Type Needs to be either "Install"
>   or "Upgrade"

Then in *"Sheet3"* or where you want to have the count of duplicated records enter the following *Array Formula (press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to enter the formula as Array Formula)* :

```
{=SUM(IF(Sheet1!$E$2:$E$4="",0,COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$E$2:$E$4,Sheet1!$E$2:$E$4)))}
```

The above formula counts the common records that comply with the criteria in both data sets *(extend the ranges for each worksheet as required excluding the headers)*.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column e on your second data sheet, in cell e2, for example, =a2&"-"&b2&"-"&c2. Then copy down. The idea is to concatenate every column should be unique. Do the same in the first data sheet. Then, cell f2 in the first data sheet should be =countif('other sheet'!e2:e50,e2) (used 50, but replace with how many rows are in the second data sheet). Copy the formula down, and anything indicated in column f of a 1 or more is a duplicate. Simply countif over the column f range of ">0".

Comment: If you need "not active", use countifS and the second condition is the status.